# Why were many users suddenly awarded the Generalist badge?

Tags: support, status-norepro, badges, generalist-badge

Lots of users were just awarded the [Generalist](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/15/generalist) badge 30 minutes ago.

What changed?

Comment: Well, since it's based on the top 40 tags, if a new tag just went into the top 40 people then active in that tag could all have gone from 19 to 20 tags with good answers.

Comment: Hmm - I just got it too - I'm curious to know what tag changed where to affect this

Comment: Looks to me like it hasn't been awarded since September 20th, Kerrek SB.  Possibly broken since then and nobody noticed until today.

Comment: @Uphill - Possible, but this is a rare badge, it isn't awarded every day.

Answer (score 8):

It's likely that one or more tags were moved into the top 40 tags recently.  This could either be a result of more growth in those tags, or the removal/deprecation of tags previously in the top 40.

With one or more new tags entering the top 40, people who previously only had 18 or 19 tags with good answers who are active in one or more of these tags, would be getting enough good answers in the top 40 tags to get Generalist.

Comment: According to [data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/76727/generalist-progression-updated), Homework wasn't a top-40 tag in June. But it is outdated... I guess you are right though - it is probably normal for many people to get the badge together, if one tag gains popularity.

Comment: Although when I run that query I am show as only having 19 qualifying flags and I was one who got the generalist flag - also there is a significant gap between 40th and 41st tag - multithreading× 29209 and asp.net-mvc-3× 28459

Comment: I upvoted this when it was a hypothetical in a comment, but I see no evidence that it's the actual correct answer.

Comment: I notice that the 39th and 40th are very close, 29214 and 29213 at time of writing. Is it possible there's a bug and only the top 39 are counted?

Answer (score 1):

Another possible cause of this occurring, especially if no one has earned the Generalist badge in the past, is that the badge [is only awarded to anyone once each of the top 40 tags are being used on at least 200 questions](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22176338#22176338).

Once someone posts a new question that brings the top 40 tags to 200 uses each, or retags a question to make that so, the badge will be awarded to everyone who qualifies for it.