# How did I get the "Generalist" badge?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bug, status-norepro, badges

This morning I got my "Generalist" badge (one of the badges I actually care about).

Stinking Badges! app claims I have only 19 tags with appropriate points. Manual labor confirms.

A default mechanism (e.g., not the data explorer) to see for *which* badges it's being given (and in my case, settle the discrepancy) would be cool.

Barring that, knowing how I managed to get the badge with only 19/20 eligible would be neat. Or if there's a way to be de-badged, since I can't figure out how I'd be qualified.

<sub>*(I.e., I'm not convinced I met the badge requirements.)*</sub>

Comment: I agree with the app. You only have 19: Java, Ruby, Ruby-on-Rails, JavaScript, Ruby-On-Rails-3, jQuery, Android, Eclipse, string, arrays, HTML, regex, Ajax, XML, JSON, SQL, Linux, MySQL, database

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Yep, that's the way I see it, too; dammit.

Comment: Take comfort; even if this is a bug just get 14 upvotes in SQL Server and you get your badge back... Alternatively, randomly tags things as Windows :-).

Comment: Is Generalist ever revoked? If not, it's possible you got it then a downvote or two knocked you down to 19 tags

Comment: @BenBrocka Possible, but I don't think so--whatever the 20th badge is/was isn't very close to 15 upvotes, hence the confusion.

Comment: Does sound like a bug then, unless you had a serial up voting reversed (I don't see one in your profile either)

Comment: see this [question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151557/why-were-many-users-suddenly-awarded-the-generalist-badge/151559#comment434787_151559) users getting the badge (including me) were surprised as well

Comment: @Mark But I checked the tags, both the API and manual checking show I shouldn't have it (AFAICT, I should double-check manually again).

Comment: As mentioned by Tim in a comment below, I think the only reasonable explanation is tag shifts.

Answer (score 4):

Without using the API (Programming? What's that?), you can manually cross reference the tags on [your profile's tags tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438992/dave-newton?tab=tags&sort=votes&page=1) with the [popular tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?page=1&tab=popular). The former shows your tags ordered by the total answer score you get for each of them, while the latter shows you the first 36 tags (so you also need to include 4 more on the next page).

With a pen and paper it shouldn't take more than 5 minutes to cross check the top 40 tags against the ones you have a score of more than 15.

Comment: Right. But that doesn't answer the question, which is "How did I get the badge", nor satisfy the feature request, IMO.

Comment: @DaveNewton Well, to verify that you meet the requirements of the badge you can use the API or do it manually. Either method should yield the same results. In your case I think it could be because one of the questions you had an answer on was retagged after the badge was rewarded, or it could be a deleted answer. Most badges are not receded even after you no longer meet the criteria for the badge. To be able to verify if, at all points in history, you've met the criteria for the badge is a much harder problem which I don't think there is a solution to.

Comment: The last tag isn't even close, though, that's the thing (the "bug" part of the question). And showing which badges qualified you for the badge is calculated anyway (the "feature" part of the question), and I think it'd be nice to have that accessible somehow. I understand how I can verify on a one-off basis.